how to get URL user visited in browser for Linux system using electron js desktop app or node js
i am developing one timedoctor like feature when the app will track, user's web browsing reports i.e. how much time user is spending on which website.
Till now i have tried get-windows package and getting window info but not the url. bellow is my o/p. can anyone help me how to get it?
code -
const getWindows = await import('get-windows');
    setInterval(async () => {
        try {
            const windows = await getWindows.activeWindow({'accessibilityPermission':true});
            console.log(windows);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Failed to get windows:', err);
        }
    }, 5000); // Checks every 5 seconds

o/p -
{
  platform: 'linux',
  title: "Anandabazar Patrika | Read Latest Bengali News, Bangla News, বাংলা সংবাদ, বাংলা খবর from West Bengal's Leading Newspaper — Mozilla Firefox",
  id: 121634817,
  owner: {
    name: 'firefox',
    processId: 9894,
    path: '/snap/firefox/4955/usr/lib/firefox/firefox'
  },
  bounds: { x: 238, y: 141, width: 1652, height: 836 },
  memoryUsage: 423927808
}

i tried using different get-windows type package. but after checking a lot, it seems active window stdout will not give urls in linux or windows system because of its architecture but macos will give.
